# How to display a calendar with events depending on the user?

Tags: users, calendar

I wanted to know if there is any way to, once a user is logged in to your page (I would use some plugin to deal with this), show them a calendar that contains the events that they were added to by another user. E.g. you were invited to a party by someone and every person that was invited when they sign in to your page, they can see the event on the calendar. Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: This can totally be done in hundreds of different ways entirely depending on a whole slew of variables.  What makes the events, where do the events reside, how are they stored in the database, is this custom code, are you using a plugin, etc.  The way your question is presented is next to impossible to answer properly because there's no detail.  So the short answer is 'yes' there is many ways to do stuff like this, but without more information that's the best anyone can offer.

Comment: Oh sorry, my intention is for a specific type of user (in this case a host user) to be able to add an event and either through email or through a username, invite other users. I have not yet started to do the user system but I think that I would use some plugin. How can I do it? @TonyDjukic

Comment: Well it is definitely possible, but I would suggest you first get the actual Event/Invite/Host system sorted out and working and once that's done, revisit this question.  Until someone knows how the event information is stored and how it is associated with users, there's really no way to give you a working answer.  Plus, the plugin of choice may have that as an option or may have snippets you can use to achieve what you're asking. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, thank you so much! @TonyDjukic